# Update multiple MVC's Views on-Model-change with PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, server-sent-events

What approach, mechanisms <s>(& probably code)</s> one should apply to fully implement Model-to-View**s** data update (transfer) on Model-State-Change event with pure PHP?

---

*If I'm not mistaken,* MVC pattern states an implicit requirement for data to be sent from Model layer to **all active** View**s**, specifying that "View is updated on Model change". (otherwise, it doesn't make any sense, as users, working with same source would see its data non-runtime and absolutely disconnected from reality)

---

But PHP is a scripting PL, so it's limited to "connection threads" via processes & it's lifetime is limited to request-response cycle (as [tereško](https://stackoverflow.com/users/727208/tere%c5%a1ko) kindly noted).

---

Thus, one has to solve couple issues:

1. Client must have a *live tunnel* connection to server (Server Sent Events),
2. Server must be able to *push* data to client (`flush()`, `ob_flush()`),
3. Model-State-Change event must be raised & related data packed for transfer,
4. (**?**) Data must be sent to **all** *active* clients (connected to same exact resource/URL) together, not just one currently working with it's own processes & instance of ModelClass.php file...

---

**UPDATE 1:** So, it seems that "simultaneous" interaction with multiple users with PHP involves implementation of WEB Server over sockets of some sort, independent of NGINX and others.... Making its core non-blocking I/O, storing connections & "simply" looping over connections, serving data....
Thus, if I'm not mistaken the easiest way is, still, to go and get some ready solution like Ratchet, be it a 'concurrency framework' or WEB server on sockets...
Too much overhead for a couple of messages a day, though...
AJAX short polling seems to be quite a solution for this dilemma....

Is simultaneous updating multiple clients easier with some different backend than PHP, I wonder?.. Look at C# - it's event-based, not limited to "connection threads" and to query-reply life cycle, if I remember correctly... But it's still WEB (over same HTTP?)...

Comment: use websockets?

Comment: In php the application's lifetime is limited by request-response cycle. You can't apply java-style structure. So there are no "multiple active views" to update. In general you would have only a single active controller and view pair. That's also why there is not practical need to have observer pattern integrated, because there is no persistent model to change.

Comment: @tereško, so, is it valid to conclude that MVC **can not** be used for scripting PLs?

Comment: @Dimi, its only difference is 2 way data transfer - not a subject. Am I wrong? Thanks for reply.

Comment: What is "PLs"? The conclusion is that you can't do the classical MVC with PHP, because classical MVC was not made for web. That does not mean, that you can apply *Separation of Concerns* to your application design, for example by using Model2 MVC approach.

Comment: @tereško, "Programming Languages" - thought it's a common abbr.
Wasn't aware of MVC Model 2, thanks for the hint.
Still, to my understanding, Model 2 doesn't differ much from MVP,  changing "user API" only, if I may say so. From View to Controller.
SoC is a great principle, but MVC isn't the only pattern implementing it, is it?
MVP, if I'm not mistaken, applies the same SoC, but IS suitable for WEB. Only "downside", compared to MVC, is View:Controller 1:1 instead of n:1...

Comment: @tereško, Then why is Internet full of articles of using MVC for PHP, even Frameworks trying to implement it...Why not to reject MVC for scripting languages (or all WEB) finally in favor of MVP?

Comment: @Dimi, seems I have evaluated your reply, finally.
My bad being junior & not knowing enough about sockets (Websockets) :D
But using Websockets with PHP seems to be kinda painfull...isn't it? The easiest way seems to be using Ratchet, but it's looks to be "a bit" overhead just for sending couple of messages an hour/half-day/day...
Could you, maybe, advice any other Websocket solution, supporting encryption?
Is using Websockets easier with Node.js?

Comment: @tereško, "Only "downside", compared to MVC _Model 2_", of course..

Comment: @Denis.Z websocket is just a name for a communication protocol. It can be implemented in dozens of different ways. Websockets can be encrypted (aka `WSS` or WebSockets over SSL). There are many examples for websockets in every programming language, so feel free to pick whichever language you are most familiar with.

Comment: I think the most important part, that you have been ignoring is: what's the purpose of your project. Real time chat? Game? Simple e-shop? CRM? It might be that you are either over-engineering or using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @Dimi, I see.. I understand that is a communication protocol, just was hoping for an easy knowledge :)

Comment: @tereško, purpose is a corporate portal of sort..for top managers. Thus I was hoping to achieve 2 goals: implement great and popular pattern & provide Views, updated on the fly when source is changed, to decrease info "travel" delay. Like push notifications of sort.. So, yeah.., seems like I'm interested in "chat" func-ty... Which leads to WWS implementation as Dimi suggested.. Still, for now I can only conclude that **full** MVC implementation with tools like PHP is _only_ possible via Websockets. Do you disagree? Correct me if I'm wrong, please, I'd really wish to sort it out finally :)